# Branding (White-Labeling) the B2C Login

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

How would one effectively implement a custom sign-in experience for multiple clients/customers while adhering to the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)?

**Requirements**

- The look and feel needs to be customized to our design but the same* for all customers
- *The logo needs to be specific to the customer

**Implementation Idea 1**

I could create a policy for each customer/client and then a custom HTML page with the img/logo different in each page but this doesn't scale very well.

**Idea**

Is there a way to pass along parameter(s) to the `Custom Page URI` defined here?

[image: Custom Page URI]

---

Reference: I've gone through this [demo example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, multiple policies would be the only approach that would work to enable your scenario.  The only fields we pass through right now is [ui-locales](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization#localizing-your-html-content), used to localize your HTML content based on the requested language.

If you're interested in bringing attention to this feature to the product team, please create an entry on https://feedback.azure.com/.  You will also be notified by the product team if there is any change for that feature.

Comment: I posted my feedback to [feedback.azure.com](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/20157850-scaling-branding-white-labeling-the-b2c-login)